# Change country name in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, countries

I want to change a country name in magento 2.2.6. Say I want to change united kingdom to 'great britain'.
All the countries are stored in a xml file at location

```
/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml
```

We can make the changes according to our locale file. I tried to change here but nothing happened (ofcourse I cleared all the caches).

In magento 1.9 I changed in the following file for this problem

```
/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml
```

So i tried to make the same change in locale folder in magento2 but nothing happened.
I found a lot of questions on magento stack exchange related to this but none has a proper answer.
So I was left on my own, what I did I changed all the files in magento 2.2 (including csv and xml), where I found united kingdom to great britain, cleared caches but to mu surprise I still get united kingdom (in country select box).

I know countries name are not stored in database and I have changed all the files where I could find united kingdom to great britain but still I get united kingdom.
I have no more method I could try for. If anyone faced the problem and could guide me in right direction.

Comment: UK and GB are not the same. I just want to mention that

Answer (score 4):

The country labels loaded using [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale/localizing). You can find more info in the `Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle` class. Data is loading in the `get` method:

```
/**
 * Get resource bundle for the locale
 *
 * @param string $locale
 * @return \ResourceBundle
 */
public function get($locale)
{
    $locale = $this->cleanLocale($locale);
    $class = get_class($this);
    if (!isset(static::$bundles[$class][$locale])) {
        $bundle = $this->createResourceBundle($locale, $this->path);
        if (!$bundle && $this->path != 'ICUDATA') {
            $bundle = $this->createResourceBundle($locale, 'ICUDATA');
        }
        static::$bundles[$class][$locale] = $bundle;
    }
    return static::$bundles[$class][$locale];
}
```

To change country label you can [create your own bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115496/how-do-i-create-icu-resource-files-for-use-in-php) (link to detailed SO answer).

---

**Another way** is to create a plugin for the `\Magento\Framework\Locale\TranslatedLists::getCountryTranslation($value, $locale = null)` method or `\Magento\Directory\Model\Country::getName($locale = null)` method and change whatever you want. It's much easiest way, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below link and it helps me to add a new country

[Add new nation into nation's list in Magento 2.3.5](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/330838/add-new-nation-into-nations-list-in-magento-2-3-5/330897#330897)